# Is There A Way To Be Notified About Google Play (Android Marketplace) Discounts?

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a website or even Android app that keeps its subscribers updated of any possible promotions/discounts going on at Google Play (previously Android Market)? I hate to miss the train.

Comment: Really, it could be useful.. great question!

Comment: As is all-too-typical of app recommendation questions, this one is attracting one-line, spammy answers.

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet would be to follow [Google Play on Google+](https://plus.google.com/106886664866983861036/posts). They always post any kind of news, including promotions for apps, music, movies...

Comment: I think he means discounts for individual apps in not the likes of the 10cent sale.

Comment: Well i got CameraZOOM for 50 cents and i am glad i did. I am interested in productivity, organization and tool apps.

Answer (score 2):

I use [AppSales](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.tsapps.appsales). It works well for me.

Comment: I use this too, and I believe it is the most popular application. It even shows a graph with past prices! It works very well.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but this app seems to be what you were looking for: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.echolu.android.apphunter

Comment: Link is now bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an alert for the Google Play store at http://dealnews.com. It will email or text you new deals come up.